# How to make a scheduled task to unlock external hdd everytime I login?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, passwords, file-unlocking

How to make a scheduled task to unlock external hdd everytime I login?

I have some WD drive which I can't remove the pswd unlock as I believe it's part of the firmware. Everytime I have to log into windows i need to unlock which isn't good as I store music on it so looking a way to automate this everytime I unlock the drive.

Answer (score 0):

If a password bother you, you can remove it:

1. Start and select All Programs
2. Select the folder labeled Western Digital
3. Click on WD Apps folder.
4. Open WD Security application
5. Select the Remove password option
6. Type the password in the Password box
7. Click Update Security Settings

[Reference to full procedure with screenshots](https://support.wdc.com/knowledgebase/answer.aspx?ID=10408#winWDSecurity)